# Как сформировать запрос с помощью sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sqlalchemy

У меня есть таблица

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = "orders"

```
id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
uuid = sqlalchemy.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
type = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
status = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
cluster_uuid = sqlalchemy.Column(UUID(as_uuid=False))
params = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy_jsonfield.JSONField(enforce_string=False, enforce_unicode=False), default="{}")
```

Также то, через что я делаю запросы.

```
db = SessionLocal()
```

Ко мне приходит некоторый словарь (d1) со значениями полей и некоторый словарь (d2) со значениями полей в поле params.
Как написать универсальный запрос поиска по данным значениям. Например:

```
d1 = {'status': 'ready',  'cluster_uuid': 'xxx'}
d2 = {"first_atr': 'my_atr', "second_atr': 'my_atr1', }
```

Тут надо найти все заказы в статусе 'ready' и кластером 'xxx' и у которого в поле params в котором лежит json поле first_atr равно my_atr и поле second_atr равно my_atr1.

Заранее я не знаю что придет в этих словарях. Как написать, чтобы поиск был одним запросом?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_ready_and_clusterXXX_inTable_Order = Order.query.filter_by(status='ready', cluster_uuid='xxx').all()
```

Ну или так, если я Вас понял правильно после комментария:

```
all_ready_and_clusterXXX_inTable_Order = Order.query.filter_by(status=d1['status'], cluster_uuid=d1['cluster_uuid']).all()
```

Comment: Вы меня видимо не очень поняли. Мне не надо прописывать конкретно параметры как тут Order.query.filter_by(status='ready', cluster_uuid='xxx'). В d1 могут быть любые значения. Мне нужно получить что-то типа Order.query.filter_by(d1) . Но когда я так пишу, то получаю ошибку

Comment: @user23519492, в чем проблема в запрос поставить значения из словаря? Напишите вместо <ready> значение d1[key]. Вариант запроса дописал выше в ответе.